# Confirm user on another system

Tags: node.js, authentication, cakephp

I am almost certain this has to exist somewhere already, and I just don't know the term for it, because I cannot find it.

I have a CakePHP app. It's not overly important that it's CakePHP except that it's not NodeJS.

I also have a NodeJS app.

Both of these apps do what they're supposed to so far.

The CakePHP app has a user session it tracks for logged in users, and I can easily determine if the current user is authorized in this application. Fantastic stuff.

Sometimes the front-end is going to call the NodeJS app. That works beautifully too. But sometimes this NodeJS app needs to serve up some content specific to that user. NodeJS and CakePHP are on different subdomains.

How can I tell the NodeJS server, securely, who the user is?

**How it works in my head**

Obviously not wanting to pass some identifier in clear text. My first thought was to encrypt a variable (UUID generated for this session and stored temporarily in a DB by the CakePHP app), send it to the front end, let it pass that over to the NodeJS when it needs to access that server, and then have the NodeJS server decrypt. It would take that decrypted value, ask PHP if it has a current session related to this variable, and if it does let NodeJS know who it is so NodeJS can spin up its own session.

- CakePHP -> Make UUID, store it related to current `user_id`, and pass to front-end all encrypted with constant X key
- Front-end -> Call NodeJS server, passing in the encrypted UUID
- NodeJS -> Decrypt UUID with X key, ask PHP if it has a user associated with it
- CakePHP -> Check for associated user, return user ID if it exists
- NodeJS -> Creates new session

In order to trick NodeJS server into thinking you're a user you're not, you have to have a properly encrypted UUID that only exists for the length of the user session on the CakePHP server at most.

**But** apparently encrypting-decrypting across different systems is apparently rife with issues.

This sort of thing certainly has to be handled already by someone. What is the pattern for *essentially* sharing sessions across different applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want JWT or JSON Web Tokens. They are specifically for this purpose https://jwt.io/introduction/

The token is a signed string that may include the identity of the user and "claims," which provide a means of providing roles, permissions or other similar authorizations for the user.